# Is it possible to automate Azure 'run as' account creation using ARM templates?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azureportal

Currently I'm deploying automation accounts using ARM templates but then I have to manually create 'Run as accounts'. Is there any way to automate this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently We do not have an option to create the Run As accounts using ARM template. 
There is already a feature request on this : **[Creation of Run As accounts using ARM Template](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/246290-automation/suggestions/18864241-creation-of-run-as-accounts-using-arm-template)**